# Creating This Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I seek assistance on compiling such a figure as:

[image]

An Eager Attempt,

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
 \tikzstyle{rect}=[draw=black, 
                   square, 
                   minimum width=100pt, 
                   minimum height = 50pt, 
                   align=center]
  \node[rect] (a) {1};
  \node[rect,below right=of a] (e) {5};
  \node[rect,right=of a] (b) {2};
    \node[rect,right=of b] (c) {3};
    \node[rect,right=of c] (d) {4};
\draw[->] (a.east)--(b.west)node[midway,yshift=12mm]
\draw[->] (a.south)--(e.west)node[midway,sloped, below,xshift=-2mm]
\draw[->] (b.south)--(e.north)node[midway, xshift=6mm];
\draw[->] (b.east)--(c.west)node[midway, yshift=12mm];
\draw[->] (c.south)--(e.east)node[midway,sloped, below,xshift=-2mm];
\draw[->] (d.south)--(e.east)node[midway,sloped, below,xshift=-2mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

@Zarko thanks so much for your assistance it is so great!

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
            calc, chains, 
            positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 9mm,
  start chain = A going right,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm,
                 align=center, on chain},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, semithick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {this is really long, short, s, this is medium}
    \node[box] {\i}; % used at first image    node names: A-\i
%   \node[box] {\i\\}; % used at second image
\node[box,below=of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$]   {it stretches quite a bit};
%\node[box,below=of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$]   {5\\};
%
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=1mm}]
    (A-1) edge (A-2) ;
    \draw[transform canvas={yshift=0mm}]
    (A-2) edge (A-3)    (A-3) edge (A-4);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-1mm}]
            (A-2) edge (A-1);
\draw   (A-1.south) edge (A-5)  (A-2.south) edge (A-5)
        (A-3.south) edge (A-5)  (A-4.south) edge (A-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is there a way to make the format stay constant despite having different length words?

Comment: Hey, I suggest you pick a more meaningfull title and make your code compilable (add \documentclass etc)

Comment: As @sheß says you are mire likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) self contained example. Then it is easi to copy and test as is. Here we have to guess document class and preamble and may end up making some wrong assumptions.

Comment: Are you aware of Graphviz ?  have a  look at some examples  at https://graphs.grevian.org/example#example-3. Your graph can be achieve with this dot code http://ix.io/2ceP and convert into tikz code with dot2tex to http://ix.io/2ceQ

Comment: much simpler dot code : http://ix.io/2cfx .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains, 
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 9mm,
  start chain = A going right,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm,
                 align=center, on chain},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, semithick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \node[box] {\i}; % used at first image    node names: A-\i
%   \node[box] {\i\\}; % used at second image
\node[box,below=of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$]   {5};
%\node[box,below=of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$]   {5\\};
%
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=1mm}]
    (A-1) edge (A-2)    (A-2) edge (A-3)    (A-3) edge (A-4);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-1mm}]
    (A-4) edge (A-3)    (A-3) edge (A-2)    (A-2) edge (A-1);
\draw   (A-1.south) edge (A-5)  (A-2.south) edge (A-5)
        (A-3.south) edge (A-5)  (A-4.south) edge (A-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the second image consider commented code line. See comments in the code.

*Note:*

- `tikzszyle` is deprecated, rather use `tikzset` or define picture element styles as options of `\tikzpicture` as is done in above MWE
- for nodes placements are used libraries `chains` and `positioning, where the first four nodes are drawn in the`\foraech` loop
- arrows between first four nodes are displaced with canvas transformation.

Comment: you are so awesome thanks a bunch--last question, if I want to change name from 1-5 where do I insert this? i tried for example replacing (A-5) but it did not work

Comment: @bvowe, you insert desired text in`\foreach` set:  `\foreach \i in {text 1,text 2,text 3, text 4}` and in node `(A-5)` in curly braces replace number 5 with desired text: `\node[box,below=of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$]   {desired text};`

Comment: thank you!! so much!!

Comment: i added one follow-up question thank you so much. i was able to modify the box text but now the image is skewed and i dont know of a remedy!

Comment: @bvowe, it will be better, if you would ask new question with link to this one.. Your original is solved ...

Comment: will do i didn't want to get in trouble for posting same question

Comment: You now make  a problem, since you new question is not visible to others, which would be willing or would like to answer you (and receive some reputation for this :-) ). To be fer to them, Please, ask new question. BTW, its look like you looking for `text width` instead of `minimum width` in nodes style definition

Answer (score 2):

You can compose such figures using Graphwiz and the dot2tex Python script converter. The dot2texi package allow you to call dot2tex from within the tex source code, using -shell-escape or -enable-write18 compiling option.
Here is is the source code which can produce this figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\begin{document}
  \begin{dot2tex}
     digraph
     { nodesep=.5;
       node [shape=square];
       {rank=same "1" "2" "3" "4"}
       "1"->"2"->"3"->"4"->"3"->"2"->"1" ;
       {"1";"2";"3";"4"}-> "5";
      }
  \end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

quoting the nodes is not mandatory if single words. You can name a node *foo* or *"foo"* displayed *foo*, but *"foo bar*" must be quoted.

You need Python and dot2tex Python script from Python repository.

Have a look to the Graphviz and the dot2texi documentations.

[image: pdflatex -shell-escape dot2tex-mwe.tex]